# JMS Listener receiving the same message over and over again

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, listener

There's one process that is enqueing messages on a queue and my server has an JMS Listener that is receiving them on the method onMessage.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "MYQUEUE", containerFactory = "jmsListenerFactory")  
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message msg) {
        ActiveMQTextMessage m=null;

        if(msg instanceof ActiveMQTextMessage){
            m = (ActiveMQTextMessage) msg;

        }
           try {
            m.acknowledge();
        } catch (JMSException e5) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e5.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

And

i have a bean jmsListenerFactory....

The process is enqueing 2 messages and my server is reading them well at the first time.. Then it gives NullPointer and keeps repeating (1 of the 2 messages) that he received..

Any ideas?

THanks a lot

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear enough on what is happening, you need to provide more information

Comment: Basicly i'm supposed to read 2 messages that are enqueued by my process.. My server is reading them but it keeps reading the last one multiple times and my server throws NullPointer exception like 7 times and the last message again... I think its because of the acknowledge.. I think this kind of acknowledge does not work on spring..

Comment: Stack trace?  Error logs?  Anything that might help someone know what is going on?

Comment: How do you create a JMS session, ideal practice is to do it like 
`Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);`
If you did it like this , then we have no need to acknowledge as documentation of Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE says that 
*With this acknowledgment mode, the session automatically acknowledges a client's receipt of a message either when the session has successfully returned from a call to receive or when the message listener the session has called to process the message successfully returns.*

Comment: Check this Link about redelivery of a message in ActiveMQ http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html